# Adding value when certain condition applies

Tags: excel, vba

I'm interested in a macro that will add a value in column P (Pass, At Risk or Failed) if column A has a certain condition - see below example.

I wonder if below macro can be used as inspiration. It was created to color a row if certain condition is met.

I'd also like the new macro to assign certain cell color in column P for value: Green for Pass, Yellow for At Risk and Red for Failed (same colors as in below macro)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Stackoverflow()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rows As Long, i As Long
Dim rngSearch As Range, rngColor As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set ws = ActiveSheet

rows = ws.UsedRange.rows.Count

For i = 1 To rows
Set rngSearch = ws.Cells(i, 1)
Set rngColor = ws.Range("A" & i, "O" & i)

If rngSearch = "Unexpected Status" Then
    rngColor.Interior.Color = 13434828
End If
If rngSearch = "At Risk" Then
    rngColor.Interior.Color = 8420607
End If
If rngSearch = "Requirements Definition" Then
    rngColor.Interior.Color = 10092543
End If

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you already tried? What are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

This would make column `P` yellow, if `rngSearch` is `"At Risk"`:

```
For i = 1 To rows
    Set rngSearch = ws.Cells(i, 1)
    Set rngColor = ws.Range("A" & i, "O" & i)

    If rngSearch = "Unexpected Status" Then
        rngColor.Interior.Color = 13434828
    End If
    If rngSearch = "At Risk" Then
        Cells(rows, "P").Interior.Color = vbYellow

    End If
    If rngSearch = "Requirements Definition" Then
        rngColor.Interior.Color = 10092543
    End If

Next i
```

The others are to be made correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, simplified

```
Dim i As Long, lngColor as Long 'It is inadvisable to declare variables which could also be the name of built in functions and objects, in your case I would not declare "rows" as a variable as it is also a property of an object
Dim varVal as Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'As general advice, avoid active and select but used fixed values, this way no confusion can exist as to which sheet is used In my example it is Sheet1, but you have to set it to the actual name of your sheet

with ws 
    For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Select Case .Cells(i, 1)   'Looks at the value of row i column A, and then below if it matches a case.
            Case "Unexpected Status"
                varVal = "Pass"
                lngColor = 13434828
            Case "At Risk"
                varVal = "At Risk"
                lngColor = 8420607
            Case "Requirements Definition"
                varVal = "Failed"
                lngColor = 10092543
            Case else
                varVal = Empty
                lngColor = 0
        End Select
        .Cells(i, 16) = varVal 'row i in column P is set to the value determined by the condition in the select case part
        If Not lngColor = 0 Then 'This value of lngColor is only present if the select case did not match and if so, the color should not be changed
           .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 16)).Interior.Color = lngColor 'Set the range of row i column A to column P to the color specified by the case select.
        End If
     Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, SilentRevolution, your macro works beautifully! :-)